# Converting an non-standard numeric date value to DATE in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-server-2012

I'm working inside SQL Server 2012 with a linked Oracle-based Server.  I'm trying to take a known date field (Oracle) to a DATE format in SS.  For example:

```
Have ------> Need
115001 | 01/01/2015
116366 | 12/31/2016
```

I see the pattern, but I don't know a) what kind of format this is (Oracle proprietary??) or b) how to convert it to string without a whole bunch of functions.  I thought it was Julian but every single Julian converter I've looked at tells me that it's not a Julian date!  Again, I'm coding in T-SQL and not Oracle SQL.

Any insight is appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: The `1115001` and `116366` are certainly not Oracle dates. Those values appear to be some variety of Julian-style date flummery - year and day-of-year offset from Jan 1, 1900, or so it appears. What type of column are they stored in (NUMBER, VARCHAR2, other)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the odd date format in question is a numerical value, then you might be able to do the following:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, odd_date % 1000 - 1, DATEADD(year, FLOOR(odd_date/1000), '1900-01-01'))
  FROM my_odd_date_table;
```

That is, we first add `odd_date` divided by 1000 *years* to the first day of the 20th century (this will give us the first day of the specified year), then add `odd_date` modulo 1000 minus one days. This should work for values in the 20th century (e.g., `95101`) as well as the 21st, etc.

If `odd_date` is a VARCHAR rather than a numerical value, you could still use the above by `CAST`ing it to a number. However that could be difficult if there are bad data in one or more values.

I don't suppose you have any control or influence over how the data are stored in the linked Oracle table? Dates should be stored as dates (that is why DBMSs have date datatypes). I've seen some odd date formats but this one is probably the oddest. It seems especially strange that one would do this in Oracle which has powerful date arithmetic and functions (better, IMHO, than SQL Server's).

Comment: Perfect!  The answer below doesn't work with numerical data.  Thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE test_julians
( cyyddd CHAR(6)
);
INSERT INTO test_julians VALUES ( '112306' );
INSERT INTO test_julians VALUES ( '112068' );
INSERT INTO test_julians VALUES ( '113001' );
INSERT INTO test_julians VALUES ( '112307' );
INSERT INTO test_julians VALUES ( '113365' );
INSERT INTO test_julians VALUES ( '115001' );

SELECT cyyddd
     , DATEADD(D,SUBSTRING(cyyddd,4,3)-1  -- add "ddd" days minus one
          , CONVERT(DATE
              , '20'
                   + SUBSTRING(cyyddd,2,2) + '-01-01') ) AS new_date
  FROM test_julians ;
```

Comment: What if you have a 20th century value?